# Any Hint for studying fork process and graph?

Tags: graph, process, fork

```
pid_t pid;  
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)  {
    fork(); 
} 
if (pid > 0)  {
    fork(); fork();
} 
fork();
```

I am new to fork. I find it quite difficult to find the number of process created and how to draw the graph .  Can anyone have any tips for me to study this. Thank You very much.

Besides, whats the meaning of fork()>0 
is it the same as pid >0 ?

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to it, you just need to understand that `fork(2)` returns twice: in the parent, and in the newborn child. In the parent it returns the process ID of the new child; in the child it returns 0. In the unlikely event that it fails, it will return -1 and no new process will be created - you probably want to do error handling in production-level code.

Just keep that in mind, and then follow the code.

In this example, let's assume that `fork(2)` is always successful. The first `fork()` happens here:

```
pid = fork();
```

After this line, there are 2 processes running: one of them has the value 0 in `pid`, the other has some other non-zero, positive value.

Then we have this:

```
if (pid == 0)  {
    fork(); 
}
```

Only the child of the previous `fork()` will have `pid == 0`, so only one of the processes forks again.

After the `if`, we have a total of 3 processes running: one has a positive value stored in `pid`, the other 2 have 0 stored in `pid`.

Now we have this:

```
if (pid > 0)  {
    fork(); fork();
}
```

The `if` is entered only in one of the processes. Inside the `if`, that process forks twice. And then the child created in the first `fork()` forks again, so by the end of the `if` we have a total of 6 processes running.

And finally:

```
fork();
```

At this point we have 6 processes running, all of them will fork again, so we end up with 12 processes.